# Show if an integral domain D satisfies DCC (descending chain condition), it must satisfy ACC (ascending chain condition).

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to prove that Artinian integral domains are also Noetherian, but I don't even know how to start the proof. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have tried that. Those proofs are hard to understand.

Comment: There is an easy proof for domains, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $d\in D$ be any nonzero element and consider the ideals $(d)\supseteq(d^2)\supseteq(d^3)\supseteq\dots$.  By the DCC, this must stabilize.  What does this tell you about $d$?

Comment: (d) is maximal ideal, so we can have a terminate sequence for ACC?

Comment: Hint 2: try to see $d\neq 0$ as an endomorphism of $D$ viewed as a module. The fact that $D$ is a domain tells you that this endomorphism is injective. The ideal $(d^n)$ is the image of the $n$-th power of your endomorphism... so, if $(d^n)=(d^{n+1})$ you get an isomorphism $(d^n)\to (d^{n+1})$... you should be able to conclude that multiplication by $d$ is an invertible endomorphism of $D$... so what does this tell you about the non-zero elements of $D$?

Comment: does that imply d is a unit, so (d) = D. Sorry if I am wrong. I am not very familiar with your terminology.

Comment: Indeed, so if non-zero element is a unit you simply don't have non-trivial ideals (so of course your Artinian domain is Noetherian).

Comment: What if the ideal is not principal ideal? In this case, the argument of d won't work?

Comment: well, a non-zero ideal $I$ contains a non-zero element $d$. But then $D=(d)\subseteq I\subseteq D$ implies that any non-zero ideal is $D$. (By the way, notice that a ring in which every non-zero element is a unit is a skew-field...)